# Eigenvectors are uniformly distributed

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

Let $M$ be a real random $d\times d$ symetric matrix. I know that since $M$ is symmteric we can always have an Eigen-Decompsotion in its Diagonal Form.

Suppose the Eigen-Vectors are such that $V_1,\cdots,V_d$ are uniformly distributed over the $d$ dimensional sphere.

Can we say anything about eigenvalues of $M$? Can we say that the eigenvalues would be close to each other?

Comment: Imagine $M$ in diagonal form. The eigenvectors are $\pm(1,0,\dots,0),\pm(0,1,0,\dots,0),\dots,(0,\dots,0,1)$. The eigenvalues could be anything (real).

Comment: I think your answer doesn't fit the question because your eigenvectors are constant and thus cannot have a density w.r.t. the sphere measure.

Comment: I thought someone posted an answer

Comment: You can construct $M$ as $M=SDS^T$ with $S$ uniformly distributed over $\mathrm{SO}(d)$ and $D$ subject to an arbitrary distribution over the diagonal matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$. Then the eigenvectors will be uniformly distributed over the unit sphere, while the eigenvalues will be distributed according to the distribution of the diagonal matrix $D$. I do not post this as an answer, because I do not have a proof that any distribution of symmetric $d\times d$ matrices, that induces a uniform distribution of the eigenvectors on the sphere, can be constructed like that.

Comment: @Reinhard did post an answer, rostader, but then deleted it, for reasons explained in Reinhard's comment.